# How to copy content in + register from local vim to remote vim in good format?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

vim1 is my local vim.vim2 is the remote vim.

```
ssh root@remote_ip
vim 
#it is vim2
```

Now some content in my vim1's + register.

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" \
        --header "Dropbox-API-Arg:  {\"path\":\"/test.txt\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}" \
        --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
        --data-binary @"test.txt"
```

I want to copy content in my vim1's + register into my vim2.

1.To input  `ctrl+shift+v` in vim2 will get bad formatted content.

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
                    --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" \
                                --header "Dropbox-API-Arg:  {\"path\":\"/test.txt\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}" \
                                            --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
                                                        --data-binary @"test.txt"
```

2.To input `:"+p` in vim2 can't do the trick.

How to copy content in + register from local vim to remote vim in good format?

Comment: Did you know you can open the remote file in your local vim? You could just paste the registry contents directly that way. Putting that aside, if you enter `:set paste` in the remote vim and then paste your text does it help?

Comment: Use paste mode together with `Ctrl-shift-insert`. Alternatively, there should be a way to forward the X-Connection and make use of the clipboard. But that is usually tricky to setup.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is pasting that messes the format. Have you tried `:set paste` before `ctrl+shift+v` in the remote vim?